# Executing IIS launcher of visual studio with command line

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I am facing an issue, I am writting a script to automatize some part in a project.

Basically, it builds a website: building the front end part, creates in IIS the application, virtual directory, application pool and then build the back end part.

But I have an error when I try to access it (here the error in the event viewer (and I don't have anything more)
[event viewer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e67u.png)
(For info the folder "bin\ISSSupport" does not exist at this very moment, it is only created after the fix explained below)

To fix it I just need to execute IIS launcher in visual studio:
[IIS launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqXfX.png)
I would like to know if there is a way doing this action with command line.

(Or even better if you know a solution to my first problem)

Comment: You might want to know a little bit more about that VSIISExeLauncher, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line).